# How to fit successive batches in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bigdata, gradient-descent

I have a large data set (>1 TB) which I wish to train using [GradientBoostingRegressor of Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn-ensemble-gradientboostingregressor).

As the size of the data is well beyond my RAM capacity, I am thinking of splitting the data into chunks and 'fit()' them one-by-one successively.

I understand setting the 'warm_start' attribute to True keeps the weights after fit(). However, it seems that I need to increase the number of estimators as well for each successive call to fit().

Is it possible to fit() all the chunks of data first before increasing the number of estimators by one?

What is the best solution to my problem, ie. fitting a super-large data set?

Comment: Only the estimators [listed here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning) are capable of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the `partial_fit` method from the SGD estimator. It's not a GBM but it works very nice and for the size of data you have you might get good results with a linear model and proper interactions.

Comment: Alright. Should I call partial_fit() statements one after another immediately? Doesn't boosting always gives a better result? Why do you think a linear model is good for my case? What proper interactions are they specifically? If I were to stick to Gradient Boosting, do you think it matters if I increase the number of estimator stages by one as I supply the next chunk of data?

Comment: Yes boosting in general might give better results. But you said you have quite a lot of data, in this case if you work on your features a linear model with interaction might be able to get nice performances. I have personally used the partial_fit method with a very large dataset and was able to get results comparable to gbms using H2O.